# On fetch return error 0x80040203

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to select the first 10 records "new_region" in MS Dynamical CRM

```
"<fetch mapping= ""logical"" count=""10"">"+ 
"<entity name='new_region'>"+ 
"<attribute name='new_regionid'/>"+ 
"</entity>"+ 
"</fetch>"+
```

Error:

```
<code>0x80040203</code>
<description>entity</description>
<type>Platform</type>
```

Please, help me!

Comment: In plugin or javascript?

Comment: the same error. No javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string getRecords = @"<fetch mapping= 'logical' distinct ='true' count='10'>
                                 <entity name='new_region'>
                                  <attribute name='new_regionid'/>
                                   <order attribute = 'new_name' descending = 'false'/>
                                  </entity> 
                                   </fetch>";
```

Comment: Ok.in order Attribute rename that as new_name.<order attribute = 'new_name' and then check

Comment: if you want order by give schema name or you can remove that one.

Comment: decided to radically change the code

    <fetch mapping= 'logical' count='5'>
    <entity name='account'>
    <all-attributes/>
    </entity>

the same error.:

    <code>0x80040203</code>
    <description>entity</description>
    <type>Platform</type>

input bad entity "new_region7" the same error

Comment: send the whole code then only we can fix this soon.

Comment: answer in separate post Thank you!